# Same string with different translation

Tags: django, internationalization, translation

I have one string that can be translated in varius part of my code in two different way.

Now if Use django-admin makemessages -l it

I get in django.po this:

```
#: pingapi/ping.py:17 pingapi/nots.py:10
msgid "may"
msgstr "maggio"
```

But I would want two different translation:

```
#: pingapi/ping.py:17 
msgid "may"
msgstr "posso"

#: pingapi/nots.py:10
msgid "may"
msgstr "maggio"
```

If I run django-admin compilemessage with the translation file posted up, I get:

```
Error: errors happened while running msgmerge
 error 'duplicate message definition'
```

Any Hints? I'm using Django.

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#contextual-markers) help?

Comment: @dgel: Not really, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah... I see. `pgettext` only provides a context string to help translators.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use gettext's context for that. Django has added support for that in 1.3 release (in code) and 1.4 (for templates), see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#contextual-markers

Update:

For example following code:

```
from django.utils.translation import pgettext, ugettext

month = pgettext("month name", "May")
month = pgettext("fifth month", "May")
month = ugettext("May")
```

Translates to:

```
#: foo/views.py:4
msgctxt "month name"
msgid "May"
msgstr ""

#: foo/views.py:5
msgctxt "fifth month"
msgid "May"
msgstr ""

#: foo/views.py:6
msgid "May"
msgstr ""
```

Each message being different and can be translated differently.

Comment: Yes, but pgettext is not only about providing information to translators, it also differentiates the message for gettext and make them different messages.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need also to pass the variable to your front-end

views.py

```
from django.utils.translation import pgettext
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):

our_masculine = pgettext("masculine", "Our")
our_feminine = pgettext("feminine", "Our")

return render(request,'index.html', {'our_masculine': our_masculine,'our_feminine': our_feminine })
```

django.po

```
#: index/views.py:16
msgctxt "masculine"
msgid "Our"
msgstr "I nostri"

#: index/views.py:17 
msgctxt "feminine"
msgid "Our"
msgstr "Le nostre"
```

index.html

```
<h4>{{ our_masculine }}</h4>
```